# Paho MQTT Golang Protocol

Tags: go, mqtt, tls1.2, paho

I'm new on Golang and mqtt.

I'm trying to connect to a broker. It works when I'm using MQTT.fx or my terminal with mosquitos.

But in my program, I create my opts with the address & clientID and when I try to connect there is an error "Unknow protocol"

> panic: Network Error : Unknown protocol
>
> goroutine 1 [running]:
>
> panic(0x347b20, 0xc820072fe0)
>
> /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:481 +0x3e6
>
> main.main()
>
> test.go:29 +0x1cd

I checked the protocol version on MQTT.fx and it's TLSv1.2.

The Paho library support TLS protocol. I'm a bit confused

Is there someone who got the same issue ?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it. Just forgot to precise the protocol at the beginning of the url.

> The type of connection required is specified by the scheme of the connection URL set in the ClientOptions struct, for example:
>
> tcp://iot.eclipse.org:1883 - connect to iot.eclipse.org on port 1883 using plain TCP
> ws://iot.eclipse.org:1883 - connect to iot.eclipse.org on port 1883 using WebSockets
> tls://iot.eclipse.org:8883 - connect to iot.eclipse.org on port 8883 using TLS (ssl:// and tcps:// are synonyms for tls://)

That works :-)